# Applying Background-color property to a div does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html, css

What do I have wrong here? This page is essentially broken into 5 divs, the middle 3 divs that represent the left, middle and right page columns are wrapped in a div with the id content.  I linked to the page if you want to view the source.  It wouldn't go in this message as a snippet very well when I tried.

Here is the style for #content

```
    #content
{
    background-color:White; 
}
```

How do I get the whole background of #content to show as white?
[link to a live version of http://beta.sc-pa.com/](http://beta.sc-pa.com/)

*ps: any other suggestions about the site would be appreciated*

[image]

Comment: Looks like the links are broken...

Comment: most are dummy links.  I'm still working through the formatting.

Comment: actually i meant the beta.sc-pa.com link, cant reach... nvm, problem solved. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `<br style="clear:both"/>` after the end of the right_content div (inside #content).

When you float elements inside a container the elements can extend outside the bound of the box - it "floats" above the box. In order to respect the boundaries you have to "clear" the floated elements by adding a clearing element (in this case a br) as a child to the container.

IE also has funky requirements a lot of the times so do a search for "ie clearfix" to find styles that make it behave like a normal browser :)

To clarify, any non-floated element in the container div will affect the height of the container. So if you had a few paragraph elements with text the container div would only be as high as that content since it is inline and not floated.

Think of a clearing element as a reset for boundaeries. After it, everything is back to normal and will continue to expand the container div's height.

Comment: Thanks.  Not only did your solution fix the issue, but you answered my next question as to why.  I understand more about that height:1%; workaround I see in css sometimes now.  (I think)

Comment: Considering the 1% issue fixes a bug in IE, there is no real logic behind it. Just a hack some clever person found so IE can get its head out of its ass ;)

Comment: I found when I turned on IE developer tools and set browser mode to IE7 standards. the fix you suggested broke, until I added height:1% to the #content style.  All is well now.

Comment: Yeah that's what you have to do in old IEs. Tis a shame!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inside #content are floated divs, when a block element has floated items inside it it doesnt have a defined height, you need to use either a defined height for #content (which probably is not what u want as it wont expand) or use a element with the clear property set to it.

example inside #content after all rest of the elements put

```
<br style="clear:both; height:0px;">
```

you would end up with

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left_content"></div>
    <div id="main_content"></div>
    <div id="right_content"></div>
    <br style="clear:both; height:0px;">
</div>
```

>

Answer (score 0):

Add a float:left to #content id. Remember if you add div's inside a container and float them, the containing div doesn't have height or width anymore. Either you can assigned a fixed with or height to that container which I don't recommend or float the #content to left and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:visible` to your `#content` div.